# Changing hour format in Bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

We are using Bootstrap timepicker which can we be found [here](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/)

Now we are using it like this `$('#timepicker1').timepicker();`

So it is showing timepicker in this way

[image]

Now we have some dependencies on the time format So what we want is the **hour** part in the if it has value in single digit suppose 8 So it should display as 08.

I am looking at the framework options but didn't find any.

Comment: Looking at the docs, I would say that this is not possible natively. You could however fork the project and include the feature by yourself

Comment: @DonaldSupertramp Thanks Donald but I don't have that much of time.

Comment: Looks like there is a way though to monkey-patch plugin.

Comment: @dfsq  monkey-patch plugin????

Comment: Sure why not, it doesn't affect original source code it case later you update to newer version.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
    var hours=e.time.hours, //Returns a string
        min=e.time.minutes,
        merdian=e.time.meridian; 

    if(hours.length==1){
        $('#timepicker1').timepicker('setTime', '0'+hours+':'+min+' '+merdian);

}
```

I think this should help. :)

Comment: First of all let me check it once. anyway +1 for you.

Comment: it is not working for me . Can you please be able to show fiddle.

Comment: I just realized that even if you set time as 08:40 AM,it will display 8:40 AM. if you really want that feature switch framework. BTW  I don't really think that adding 08 will make the UI look good or make it functional. Good Luck. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope I am not too late.  Try using the TimePicker's change method:

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
    var timePicked = $('#timepicker1').val();

    if(timePicked.length < 8)   
        $('#timepicker1').val("0" + timePicked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at it, as that particular picker is no longer maintained and doesn't have the functionality you seek it looks like you are going to have to fork the project and get your hands dirty implementing the styling. Or use another picker.

Personally I'd timebox this to say 1 hour and see if you can get it done if you are short of time, otherwise use another component.

Comment: I don't have that much time. Can you suggest me some quick fix.

Comment: get another component, I haven't looked at it but you could try this, http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/

Comment: I don't want to migrate to some other plugin.

Comment: then you must fix it, as the author has said you can fork it you can do so and improve it for everyone, there is a fork already here: https://github.com/rendom/bootstrap-3-timepicker maybe they implemented what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
    var hours=e.time.hours, //Returns an integer
        min=e.time.minutes,
        merdian=e.time.meridian;
    if(hours < 10) {
        $(e.currentTarget).val('0' + hours + ':' + min+' '+merdian);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But I have created a code for time picker. I will be very helpful for multiple time picker also.

This code works for 01:00:00 that means H:i:s

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function (e) {
    let timePicked = $(this).val();
    (timePicked.length < 8) ? $(this).val("0" + timePicked) : '';
});
```

This code works for only H:i

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function (e) {
        let timePicked = $(this).val();
        (timePicked.length < 5) ? $(this).val("0" + timePicked) : '';
    });
```